# Google Chrome Browser odd behavior - saves $_SESSION data on closing browser?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

On Firefox and Internet Explorer, when you close the browser while being logged into a website (e.g. Yahoo mail) it automatically logs you out.

However on Google Chrome (with Sync enabled), the $_SESSION seems to be stored even when the browser is closed. Its easy to reproduce,
    a) Log into yahoo mail, on Chrome (with sync enabled)
    b) Close your browser without logging out of yahoo mail
    c) Open a new browser
    d) Got mail.yahoo.com. This will allow you into yahoo mail without requiring you to log in.

I am using yahoo mail as a example because it'll be easier to relate to. I have same exact issue with my website login system. I am worried about my users logging into their accounts from a public account and closing their Chrome browsers not realizing that the next person that comes along and open the browser window might be able to log into their account.

Has anybody come across this. Does anybody know how to fix this i.e. ensure that the session is closed and user logged out when a Chrome Browser is closed?

Comment: Chrome will continue to run in the background so something like the Gmail chrome-extension can continue to give you desktop notifications after you close your browser window. That may also be keeping the session active.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @chiliNUT. I think you are right. This happens because its still running in the background - I hadnt noticed this until you pointed it out. There is a chrome browser icon in the system tray. If I kill that process, then it logs me out appropriately. Is there a way to force the logout when the Chrome browser itself is closed?